# How to draw line with a shape at a specific interval?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

My code is

```
f = myfunc1(...); % (f=1x4 cell) % (f{i} : 1x1000000 matrix)
g = myfunc1(...); % (g=1x4 cell) % (g{i} : 1x1000000 matrix)
color = {'red', 'blue', 'green, 'black};
leg = {'~~~', '~~~', '~~~', '~~~'};
for i=1:4
    figure(1);
    plot(f{i}, color{i});
    hold on;grid on;

    figure(2);
    plot(g{i}, color{i});
    hold on;grid on;
end
for i=1:2
    fig = figure(i);
    legend(leg);
end
```

This gives two figures, each of whom has four lines with different colors.
However, they are distinguishable in the monitor, but they are not on black distinguishable on the black-and-white printed paper.
Hence, I tried to add some shapes, e.g., circle, star, dot, and etc.
I want to put one type of shape on each line. (Not every point but every 100 point.)

Actually, I could do that additionally drawing shape on the result, but the legend is not changed. Is there any function to draw with a shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line object created by the `plot` command has a `MarkerIndices` property that you can use to obtain what you want:

```
x = linspace(0,10,1000);
y = exp(x/10).*sin(4*x);
plot(x,y,'-*','MarkerIndices',1:10:length(y))
```

Example taken from the MATLAB documentation at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-line-plot-with-markers.html

Note that this interacts well with legends too.